# Cannot make git ignore a directory

Tags: linux, git, version-control, gitignore

My project is very old. Multiple things happened with `/.gitignore` and the directory in question (`/cache/`).

Right now when I `clone` the project the directory does not get created.
I have only one (root) `.gitignore` and for test purposes I emptied it.

`~/.config/git/ignore` does not exist, `/.git/info/exclude` is empty.

The problem is that whatever I do (create or delete) with the directory `git status` shows no changes and `git rm --cached cache/` finds no entries, so I can neither add the directory to git nor delete and ignore it.

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: It sounds like git isn't even tracking the file. Have you tried doing `git add --all` after you create the directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git tracks files¹, not directories. Directories get created only when there is a file that needs to live inside them.

A common technique for including "empty" directories in Git is to create an empty *file* inside them:

```
touch cache/.gitkeep
git add cache/.gitkeep
git commit
```

Push that up to your shared repository and then try cloning again. You should end up with a `cache/` directory containing a single file: `.gitkeep`. If your goal is to create the directory but ignore its contents, you'll want to have something like this in your `.gitignore` file:

```
cache/*
!cache/.gitkeep
```

¹Actually, it doesn't really track files either. It tracks *content*, but in general thinking of Git as tracking files is pretty safe.